# Is there an Arduino simulator that runs on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-os, simulator

I need to simulate my Arduino project with other circuit components before implementing the project. Is there a decent simulator that runs on Mac platform?

Answer (score 3):

There is a decent program called [Simulator for Arduino](http://virtronics.com.au/Simulator-for-Arduino.html) made by Virtronics. Although it is made to run only in windows, you could run it in a [WINE environment](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX#head-43b0651931c700b0f796ab7d5280a08eb58d51e0). WINE allows windows programs to be ran in Mac and Linux OS.

Comment: Ouch - "Pointers not implemented - some sketches with pointers may run but generally pointers don't work"

Comment: I'll try to install on Mac and see if it works

Comment: web-based Arduino simulator from wokwi,com will even work on Mobile platform. It is easier than ever to keep learning Arduino and tinkering with the projects